# Retrofit + RxJava - cache / publish and retry on error?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have the following requirement:

1. Multiple observers (fragments) need to subscribe to a data source.
2. Activity will start a network request. Once the request is successful, each observer will receive the result.

I've trying to do it using cache / publish operators, but the issue is when initial request returns an error. At this point I wish to reset the stream and subsequent calls to the method should run a new network request instead of returning an error each time.

Here's what I have currently.

```
private Flowable<List<Data>> dataObservable;

private Flowable<List<Data>> getData(){
    if(dataObservable == null){
        dataObservable = apiService.getData()
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    dataObservable = null;
                })
                .cache();
    }
    return dataObservable;
}
```

This works, but the code feels wrong. There's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the observable ahead of time, and it won't actually do anything until something subscribes to it. That's one less `null` value to worry about.

You can use the `retry()` operator, or a variant of it, to automatically retry the network operation on an error.

Finally, the `cache()` operator will ensure that only one network connection subscription is active. Each subscriber will get any updates from the observable, and will be oblivious to any network errors experienced.

```
Flowable<List<Data>> dataObservable = apiService.getData()
  .retry()
  .cache();
```

Comment: Issue is that retry() operator keeps on retrying indefinitely, without any input from me.

Comment: There are several `retry()` operators taking various arguments. This is a good introduction: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no operator for that.

The issue was discussed at [Observable, retry on error and cache only if completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195722/observable-retry-on-error-and-cache-only-if-completed)
and [Plato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33204387/330779) created a nice tiny lib for that
[platoblm/rx-onerror-retry-cache](https://github.com/platoblm/rx-onerror-retry-cache/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/rx/utils/OnErrorRetryCache.kt).